# ordered list ul li nested tree in java from MYSQL

Tags: java, mysql, database, jsp, html-lists

I am trying to make ul li nested tree by using records. Records are coming from DB table. Here is the snapshot of my table.
[image]

And I am trying to get these record in java and want to display on html page. For this I am using JSP page. Here is sample of my JSP Page

```
<ul  id="org" style="display:none">
            <li><a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-inline ui-btn-hover-e ui-btn-up-e"><span class="ui-btn-inner"><span class="ui-btn-text" style="font-size:10px;">3214657890<br/>Root<br/>SAP<br/>SSE</span></span></a>
                <ul id="main_child_ul" class="children">

              <%
              String x=empTree.Operator();
               System.out.println(x);

               %>



              </ul> 
            </li>
        </ul>
```

And here are my JAVA functions

```
public ResultSet getSavedTree() throws SQLException{
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {   
             s = ds.createStatement();           

             rs = s.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM pep.employee_tree order by reporting_to;");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return rs;

        }
```

And Operator function

```
public String Operator()
    {
        String x="";
        try {
            ArrayList<EmployeeJSONObj> arraylist = new ArrayList<EmployeeJSONObj>();              

            ResultSet SavedEmployeesTree = getSavedTree();
            while(SavedEmployeesTree.next())
            {
                EmployeeJSONObj emp = new EmployeeJSONObj();
                emp.setName(SavedEmployeesTree.getString("sap_code"));
                emp.setParentId(SavedEmployeesTree.getString("reporting_to"));
                arraylist.add(emp);
            }
            x=recursiveTree(arraylist,"-1");
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return x;

    }
```

AND Recursive function

```
public String recursiveTree(ArrayList<EmployeeJSONObj> categories , String parent)
    {
        String ret = "<ul>";
        String sub ="";

        try {
            //String xx=categories.getString("sap_code");
            for(int i=0;i<categories.size();i++)
            {
                if(categories.get(i).getParentId().equals(parent))
                {
                    ret += "<li><a href=='#'>"+ categories.get(i).getName() +"</a>";
                    sub = recursiveTree(categories,categories.get(i).getParentId());
                    if(sub != "<ul></ul>")
                        ret += sub;
                    ret += "</li>";
                }
            }
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   

        return ret+"</ul>";
    }
```

And here is my JAVA Employee Class

```
public  class EmployeeJSONObj {
    private String name;
    private String parentID;
    private List<EmployeeJSONObj> children = new LinkedList<>();
    EmployeeJSONObj()
    {

    }
    public void setName(String n)
    {
        name=n ;
    }
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
    public void setParentId(String pid)
    {
        parentID=pid;
    }
    public String getParentId()
    {
        return parentID;
    }

    public List<EmployeeJSONObj> getChild()
    {
        return children;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "name: " + name + ", children = " + children;
    }

}
```

This is what I tried to make it recursive but when I run this code it give me stack overflow error. I think it is running infinite of time.

Please help I need help here on this project.

Answer (score 0):

In your JSP file example. You used.

```
 <%
     String x=empTree.Operator();
     System.out.println(x);

 %>
```

Here, `System.out.println(x);` display the result on console, not in JSP page. Use `out.println(x)` to display result in JSP page.

Answer (score 0):

Well I think your recursive function is not ending never.

Try to pass the list with one element less on each recursive call.

**List newList = categories.subList(0,categories.size() -1);**

sub = recursiveTree(**newList** ,categories.get(i).getParentId());

```
public String recursiveTree(ArrayList<EmployeeJSONObj> categories , String parent)
    {
        String ret = "<ul>";
        String sub ="";

        try {
            //String xx=categories.getString("sap_code");
            for(int i=0;i<categories.size();i++)
            {
                if(categories.get(i).getParentId().equals(parent))
                {
                    ret += "<li><a href=='#'>"+ categories.get(i).getName() +"</a>";
                    **List newList = categories.subList(0,categories.size() -1);**
                    sub = recursiveTree(**newList** ,categories.get(i).getParentId());
                    if(sub != "<ul></ul>")
                        ret += sub;
                    ret += "</li>";
                }
            }
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   

        return ret+"</ul>";
    }
```

Comment: Guys thanks for help. I modified the recursive condtion and it is working now. Great thanks @Aitor.

Comment: @user2777070 I'm glad to hear that. If you found my answer useful please upvote it. If it was the right answer, please mark it as the right one. Regards